# Code continues to execute without awaiting

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, async-await

I have a structure like this:

```
export class SomeDerived extends SomeBase implements OnInit{
    public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        await super.ngOnInit();
        this.getBy(this.x);
    } 
}

export class SomeBase implements OnInit {
    public x: any;
    public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        try{
            await this.fetch();
        }catch(e){}
    }

    public async fetch(): Promise<void> {
        const someId = await this.requestService.fetchId().toPromise().id;
       this.x = await this.requestService.fetchX(someId).toPromise();
    }
}
```

well, when i run this, this.x in SomeDerived is undefined because it is not awaiting for super.ngOnInit() results to be set in SomeBase, and it is continuing. I am not very good with asynchronous code, can you please help me understand why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

```
 public async fetch(): Promise<void> {
   return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
      const someId = await this.requestService.fetchId().toPromise().id;
      this.x = await this.requestService.fetchX(someId).toPromise();
      resolve();
   });
 }
```

You need to return a `Promise` otherwise you can not use `await`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a base component that is implementing the ngOnInit method. In this base component you are creating another method (for example onComponentCreated) that is called after the async method was executed. Your derived class then is not implementing the OnInit but it is implementing your base class and therefore is executing the onComponentCreated.

```
export class SomeDerived extends SomeBase {
      ................
      public onComponentCreated(): Promise<void> {
         ........
         this.getBy(this.x);
         ........
      } 
    }

 export class SomeBase implements OnInit {
     public x: any;
     ........
     public ngOnInit() {
       ........
       this.fetch().subscribe(result => {
          this.x = result;
          this.onComponentCreated();
       });
     }

    public abstract onComponentCreated();


    public async fetch(): Observable<void> {
        return new Observable(observer => {       
           const someId = await this.requestService.fetchId().toPromise().id;
           const result = await this.requestService.fetchX(someId).toPromise();
           observer.next(result)
       });
     }
    }
```